# android getPosition and sorting

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to sort by one field and view row position of another field.
For example, having names in the first field and age in the second field Order By name and view in a third field a position from youngest to oldest.

```
Ann 25years 2 // 2nd position in the age.
Joe 30years 3 // 3rd position in the age.
Ron 20years 1 // 1st position
```

I would like to have getposition from "column age", is it possible?

My code

Show_Activity

```
///ON RESUME    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

    datasource.open();
        Cursor cursor = datasource.Query(filter);

        String[] columns = new String[] { "swimm_pos", "swimm_date","swimm_lap", "swimm_stroke", "swimm_time", "swimm_media", "swimm_efficiency", "swimm_note" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.swimm_pos, R.id.swimm_date, R.id.swimm_lap, R.id.swimm_stroke, R.id.swimm_time, R.id.swimm_medialap, R.id.swimm_efficiency, R.id.swimm_note};

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            R.layout.list_layout, 
            cursor, 
            columns, 
            to);

    adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
              if (view.getId() == R.id.swimm_pos)
                { 
                  rowcounter = cursor.getPosition()+1;
                  String s = String.valueOf(rowcounter);
                  TextView tv = (TextView)view;
                  tv.setBackgroundColor(0xFF558866);
                  tv.setText(s);
                  return true;
            }
              return false;}
        });

    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    datasource.close();
}
```

DBAdapter

```
public Cursor Query(String filter) {
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery
                    ("select _id, swimm_pos,swimm_date, swimm_lap,swimm_stroke,swimm_time,swimm_media,swimm_efficiency,swimm_note from swimm_table order by cast("+filter+" as integer) asc", null);
            return cursor;
        }
.........
```

and I've buttons to change sort

```
....
    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.btn_sort_date:
            filter = "swimm_date";
            datasource.open();
                cursor = datasource.Query(filter);        
                adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this, 
                    R.layout.list_layout, 
                    cursor, 
                    columns, 
                    to);
```

Comment: You want to modify the display of the list sorted by name?
Where are you getting the data from?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different ways. Either you can sort the ages by writing code and then inserting in table or you can have ages of persons in a different table and make it `ORDER BY`(by default ascending order) age. Mark the ages table by one column as Primary key autoincrement. Then inner join with the table that contains names of persons. So that you would get the table which you mentioned above.

Comment: up I edit with my real code (name and age was an example to try to explain better). I would like rowcounter always = the row order position of swimm_lap. (2 laps = 1, 20 laps = 2, 40 laps = 3...) also when I set order by swimm_time or order by swimm_stroke...